# Crashlytics on iOS Enterprise apps

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric, ios-enterprise

How can I get the crashes to show on Fabric.io dashboard/site on Enterprise Apps?

We have clients that have Enterprise Apple Developer Accounts, we deliver the app by only sending them the .IPA. After installing Crashlytics and integrating to the project, the version and build shows up on Fabric.io, and I have also uploaded the dSYMS in Fabric. But I still could not get the crashes.

I am forcing a crash by `[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash];` in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the AppDelegate just right after I initialize Fabric/Crashlytics.

Comment: Crashlytics doesn't know/care about how the app is distributed, it should work in all cases (even when run on your own dev device while developing)

Comment: But I believe you have to upload the dSYMS right? Because for apps we upload on iTunes Connect, we can download the dSYMS to Fabric using FastLane. Not sure if there is a way to do this with an Enterprise app.

Comment: The symbols are available in the archive on the Mac where you created the build.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I got it to work now. According to this guide:

https://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/121064-why-don-t-i-see-data-from-my-first-crash-in-the-da

> Make sure our SDK line is after all other 3rd-party SDK lines. (We
>   need to be last one called in your appDidFinishLaunching method.)
>
> Force a crash and then relaunch the app. Xcode must be disconnected to
>   stop it from intercepting the crash report. To disconnect Xcode,
>   follow the instructions here.
>
> If you're using our [Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash]; to test
>   crashing, make sure it's not in the appDidFinishLaunching method.

My mistake is that I was forcing the crash in appDidFinishLaunching method.
I tried force crashing into one of my IBActions and I see the crash in Fabric Dashboard.

Comment: My crashes reported to firebase but every crashes line is 0, could you help me please?